# NETSparkle not showing release notes

Tags: .net, auto-update, release-notes

I am currently attempting to use NetSparkle version 1.0.84 to display release notes from HockeyApp's AppCast format which uses query parameters in the download url. Unfortunately, this caused my release note to not show up to the user when the "new update available" window comes up. The release notes are in the form of:

```
<description>
<ul> <li>fix 1</li> <li>fix 2</li> <li>fix 3</li> </ul>
</description>
```

I have also seen the release notes appear like this in an appcast:

```
<sparkle:releaseNotesLink>http://somewebsite.com/releasex.x.html
</sparkle:releaseNotesLink>
```

with releasex.x.html being:

```
<html> <ul> <li>fix 1</li> <li>fix 2</li> <li>fix 3</li> </ul> </html>
```

Any ideas on what could be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question:  after I posted this, someone made a patch for NetSparkle to recognize HTML that has been embedded in the appcast.  [patch](http://netsparkle.codeplex.com/workitem/20440)